# Dimension capacity of a set

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

The question is very direct.

> How can I calculate the dimension of capacity of the set: $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$?

---

I know that the dimension of capacity of a set $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ ( but I' m not $100\%$ sure if I could define the same for$\mathbb{Q}^n$) is $\dim A=\displaystyle\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{inN(\varepsilon)}{\ln\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)}$ if the limit exists.

Now I find that for a closed set the dimensions of Minkowski-Bouligand and Hausdorf-Besicovitch are the same $D_{0}=D_{MB}=D_ {HB}$ while if a set is not closed, the Hausdorff-Besicovitch dimension may differ from the other two. Now I don't really know if this can help me and if I can use it in some way...

---

**Edit:**

The fact is that the box-counting doesn't distinguish dense subset. For this reason I've tried to find some other methods to resolve this problem and I find something about the two other type of dimension even if I don't really know if these can help me. –

Comment: I have no clue what this question is about but I love everything about it

Comment: It would help if you define the term "dimension capacity". I originally assumed you meant what is variously called box dimension, Minkowski dimension, etc., but given that you later mention the Minkowski-Bouligand dimension, I'm not so sure now. Also, while a reader might guess what $D_{MB}$ and $D_{HB}$ represent, what does $D_0$ represent? Or instead of defining your dimension notions, pick a standard textbook (there are many), such as by Falconer (he has three texts) or Mattila or Edgar (he has two texts), use the exact terms in that book and tell us which book the terms are from.

Comment: I'm very sorry for all this confusion. Yes the question is about the dimension of capacity of my set (or box dimension/ box counting). The fact is that the box-counting doesn't distinguish dense subset. For this reason I've tried to find some other methods to resolve this problem and I find something about the two other type of dimension even if I don't really know if these can help me.